# Update a current object given an object of the same type

Tags: java, oop

Let us suppose we have the following class:

```
class Credentials implements ICredentials{
    String name;
    String surname;
    String email;

    public void update(ICredentials updatedCredentials){
            // do stuff here
    }

}
```

I would like to update the fields of the current class (the strings above) , using an object of the same type, without using getters or setters. Is there a way?

PS: noob here.

Comment: What methods does `ICredentials` have? I think without using getters and setters, this will just not work... Why don't you want to use getters and setters?

Comment: Why don't you want to use getters and setters? Is there a programmatic reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the object that you want to update to a `ICredentials` method  that updates its content :  `updateParam(Credentials)`.
Add this method in the interface and `Credentials` that implements it could use private fields of the parameters as an instance of a class can access to private fields without getters.

```
class Credentials implements ICredentials{

    public void update(ICredentials updatedCredentials){
         updatedCredentials.updateParam(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateParam(Credentials credentialsToUpdate){
         credentialsToUpdate.name= name;
         credentialsToUpdate.surname = surname;
         credentialsToUpdate.email= email;
    }
}
```

But this is convoluted enough.
The real issue in your actual logic is that you want to pass `ICredentials` as parameter that is not necessary a `Credentials`. In these conditions, the interface needs to provide a way to extract the name, surname and email information.
You don't have to consider these methods strictly as *getters* but as methods required to fulfill the interface contract.
Without it, to extract data from the interface you should do convoluted things or downcasting from the interface to the subclass or still worse...

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you! I will look into what you say and try to come up with a nicer design.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `updatedCredentials` is the same instance of `Credential`, one way is that you can directly assign

```
public void update(ICredentials updatedCredentials){
    Credentials cred = (Credentials) updatedCredentials;
    this.name = cred.name;
     //rest of it
}
```

Remember you need to declare the variable as `public`. But this process is very ugly. If you can use `getter` and `setter` that could be nice solution and it is the best practice